# How to make app not showing "No Internet Connection" message after downloading file in WebView?

Tags: java, android, webview, connection

So, I've added message to my app if there is no connection in the WebView, like this:

```
webviewku.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView webView, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            try {
                webView.stopLoading();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                webView.goBack();
            }

            webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Anda tidak memiliki koneksi internet. Sambungkan perangkat anda ke internet dan coba lagi.");
            alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Coba Lagi", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                    startActivity(getIntent());
                }
            });

            alertDialog.show();
            super.onReceivedError(webView, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        }
    });
```

Notes:
webviewku = my WebView name;
*Alert message and button are shown in Bahasa Indonesia.*

Anyway, I'm using the whole webview as the main window (I mean, I convert my website to an app), and I have many page that require downloading things. I'm using No Internet Connection message to make sure that the domain of my website won't show and won't be seen by anyone when there is no internet connection.

So, I make this app has the ability to download file. But, because webview doesn't load any change and only download the file, the "No internet connection" message comes.

How to make this message doesn't come after downloading file?

Answer (score 0):

You can track the downloading of the file once completed dismiss the alert dialogue
with the help of 
 alertDialog.dismiss();

Comment: Thankyou for your comment, but it actually doesn't work, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Jordandreas I have edited my comment ,Please check.

Comment: thankyou before. Well, I need a little help, I'm totally a newbie in this Android Studio. The `alertDialog` and the download code are in the different webView heading, the `alertDialog` is in `webviewku.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient())` and the download code is in `webviewku.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener())`, which means these two codes are not in the same field and I can't just write `alertDialog.dismiss();` below `webviewku.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener())`. So, what should I do?

I'm sorry, really really sorry, I'm totally a newbie :(